# How much disk space do you need for Kubernetes Minikube

Tags: kubernetes

I want to install Kubernettes Minikube (both Linux OS and Minikube) on a 56GB SSD drive. The Kubernettes web site is silent on disk space requirements for [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#persistent-volumes) binaries and storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a little digging into the source on the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/pkg/minikube) and found:

The minimum disk size for the VM is [2000MB](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/8162162f6c201f1877cc4c131bbefd88b17e5250/cmd/minikube/cmd/start_flags.go#L113) ([Validation Code](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/5de765023a2f33c89bb721d785f9d357f094b99e/cmd/minikube/cmd/start.go#L1271))

```
    MinimumDiskSizeMB   = 2000
```

The default disk size for the VM is [20GB](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/8162162f6c201f1877cc4c131bbefd88b17e5250/cmd/minikube/cmd/start_flags.go#L75)

```
    DefaultDiskSize     = "20g"
```

Answer (score 11):

The minikube install by default around 16GB VM, you can configure your VM disk space using the:

```
minikube start --vm-driver kvm2 --disk-size 20GB
```

This way it will allocate 20GB diskspace to your VM.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Where is this documented?

Comment: It's actually `--disk-size 20GB` 
@BarryMSIH - `minikube start --help`